# Options for sharing dashboards with sensitive information with PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I have a dashboard I've built using Power BI, that contains sensitive information.  I want to share this dashboard with external users outside of my organization, that do not and will not have PowerBI.

From everything I've read, it appears I have a few options:

1. The external recipient of the dashboard would need to download Power BI Pro (from my understanding, they won't be able to view my dashboard with anything other than Power BI Pro?)
2. I somehow embed my dashboard in a Sharepoint which the external recipients have access to - but from what I've read, this seems likely to fail since they don't have Power BI.
3. I publish dashboard to the web, and have no way to password protect or restrict access.

Are these my only options?  Am I correct in that anyone I wish to share the dashboard with needs Power BI Pro to view, or I need to publish it to the open web and let it be publicly available?

If this is the case.. this is just one more reason I am disenchanted by Power BI.

Comment: You can do this with a Power BI Premium license.

Comment: Can you explain further? Which part can I do?  Share directly?

Comment: From what I understand, this still costs $$ and so is not feasible option for me.

Comment: Power BI premium is really effective when you are sharing with a lot of users. That being said, both pro and premium are going to cost you and there is no getting around that.

Comment: So, to go back to my original question: do I have it right in that those 3 options are in fact my only 3 options?

Comment: I can't be a 100% certain, but it looks like they are the only available options. The only other option would be to share the Power BI file directly and ask the users to refresh it (which is not ideal)

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you can do this for free. I have done it with premium though.

Comment: "The only other option would be to share the Power BI file directly and ask the users to refresh it (which is not ideal)" - can a user without power BI open up a .pbix file?  Also, the underlying data is coming from an internal SQL database from my org, so I don't know how that would be refreshed unless I re-sent the file..?

Comment: The power Bi desktop software is needed, but it's free. And you are right, if the user does not have access to the data, they won't be able to refresh

Comment: If this is not a one time thing, the only way would be a pro or premium license

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other options in addition to these you mentioned already (i.e. directly sharing through adding users to the workspace, embed in SharePoint and Publish to web).

Sharing (except Publish to web, which is public) require both the publisher and the consumer to have Power BI Pro licenses (which is not the case for you). Purchasing Power BI Premium (P SKUs only) will allow you to share reports with non-Pro (i.e. Power BI free users), but they still needs Power BI licenses (although free). Also this will costs you thousands per month and has annual commitment, which means you can't buy this for a month or two.

If this doesn't work for you, you can also:

- Export these reports to PDF or PowerPoint and share the files with them.
- If the report imports the data (see [Dataset modes in the Power BI service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-dataset-modes-understand#import-mode)), you can send them the .pbix file directly. It can be opened in Power BI Desktop even without having no Power BI account at all.
- Publish the report to local instance of Power BI Report Server, where you can control who can access the report. You need either Power BI Premium (P SKUs) or SQL Server Enterprise with software assurance for that.
- Embed the report using Power BI's API into custom written application, implementing app owns data scenario (see [Tutorial: Embed Power BI content into an application for your customers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embed-sample-for-customers) and for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56409362/is-there-any-way-to-embed-power-bi-reports-and-dashboards-in-vb-net-or-c-sharp-d/56418991#56418991)).

Comment: Wow, thanks for the feedback all.  I'm a bit shocked at how complicated a seemingly simple task is made by Power BI.  There should be an option to host your visualization on the web and simply have the option to restrict access via a password and login.  In Tableau Server, it's as easy as that.

Comment: Andrey - I may explore just sending the client a .pbix file and have them download Power BI Desktop in order to open and view it.  My .pbix file reads data off an internal SQL database - if that's the case, would the external consumer be able to view the visualization?  i.e. is the SQL data saved in the dashboard, or no?

Comment: If your report imports the data, then your clients can see it, even if they can't connect to the database. If your report uses DirectQuery, then you can't use this trick.

Comment: I'm using "Get Data", and then selecting "SQL Server."  I'm guessing this is the same is importing the data into my report, thus being visible if I send the file?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends on the storage mode (see the link from my answer). It is set when you enter the data source information (see the radio buttons in this screenshot for example https://dpspowerbi.blob.core.windows.net/powerbi-prod-media/powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powerbi-desktop-use-directquery/20170106084048/directquery_2a.png)

Comment: Ah gotcha.  Ok, yes, I believe I did a direct import rather than a directQuery.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Andrey's answer, depending on the number of users you can use [Azure AD B2B](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/what-is-b2b) so you can have guest users access your Power Bi Reports and allocated work-spaces. However it depends on the number.

For example, if you need to add 100 users, and you pay for the Power BI Pro licenses then it would be cheaper to design a basic portal and use the Power BI Embedded option and build you own basic web portal to embedded the reports in (The app owns data scenario). The basic [A SKU's](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/power-bi-embedded/) start around the same price as about 73 Pro licenses, or £570 per month. There will be extra cost in development of the portal and the running costs on top of the Embedded price.

If your external end user is going to pay for the Pro license, then Azure AD B2B could work for you.