# share a report in power Bi embeded with other users

Tags: powerbi

Hello I want to know if it is possible embedded a report of power bi in a web using power BI embedded and if the report embedded is accessible to all the people without use a Microsoft account.

I don't know if I'm Clear, I want to know if I have to pay just one license of power bi to develop this report and embedded in the web site or if I have to pay a license for each user of my application that want to see the report.

Comment: Please read tags before adding them. The `embedded` tag isn't about embedding a resource but about embedded devices. As such please remove the embedded tag.

Answer (score 0):

There are two modes for embedding - `user owns data` and `app owns data`.

With the first one each of your users needs a Power BI account. For more information see [Tutorial: Embed Power BI content into an application for your organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-your-organization).

With the later one, you need only one Power BI account (it's called `master account`) to access the report, and your users doesn't need Power BI accounts at all (but probably you will want to authenticate them in some other way in your application). For more information see [Tutorial: Embed Power BI content into an application for your customers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers). So basically `app owns data` is what you are looking for.

There are many answers how to implement these. For example you can see [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56409362/is-there-any-way-to-embed-power-bi-reports-and-dashboards-in-vb-net-or-c-sharp-d).