# Power BI - generating embed code for a dashboard instead of a report

Tags: powerbi

I can't figure out how to generate an embed code for a Power BI Dashboard - see picture of dashboard below.  There is a "more options" on the dashboard, but no actual way to get an embed code in order to embed on a public website.  I have this in report form (it's just the map, so only a one-page report) and I can generate an embed code for the report.

[image]

If I click on the dashboard itself, it just takes me back to the report, and any embed code I generate there just embeds the report, which annoyingly is not centered and includes the Power BI menu at the bottom:

[image]

Am I missing something here?  Where is the option to get an embed code for a dashboard?

Comment: Take a look at [Tutorial: Embed Power BI content into an application for your customers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-sample-for-customers). This is the proper way of embedding Power BI elements, which will give you flexibility to control the appearance too. There are lots of questions here how to do that, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56409362/is-there-any-way-to-embed-power-bi-reports-and-dashboards-in-vb-net-or-c-sharp-d) one.

Comment: Andrey, thanks but not sure I understand.  All I'm trying to do, is use the embed iframe method in a public website.  It's not a custom application.  I just figured if you could embed a report, why wouldn't you be able to embed a dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

The [Publish to Web](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-publish-to-web) option in Power BI is for reports only, not for dashboards or Apps. Any other embedding for a publicly accessible object must use the custom app approach, with the relevant Premium or Embedded Service.