# Is it possible to embed power bi reports using VB.net code?

Tags: vb.net, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, power-bi-report-server

I would like to create Power BI reports programmatically using VB.NET.

I did not have any idea yet, can someone tell me is it possible to done all the data retrieval, visual design and setting configurations using VB.NET?

Comment: Is your question to embed a report or create a dataset & report programmatically? If it is to embed, what kind of VB. Net app?

Comment: Use vb.net to retrieve data from database then create power bi report. I'm using visual studio.

Comment: Yes, you can use PBI Embedding in VB.NET solution. Follow the following instructions here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56409362/is-there-any-way-to-embed-power-bi-reports-and-dashboards-in-vb-net-or-c-sharp-d